# Select from table where count from another related table is only one

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've tow tables both are related by id ... I want a single query using eloquent or mysql statements to do below ... :

```
  clients
 -----------
| Id | name |
 -----------
| 1  | name1|
 -----------
| 2  | name2|
 -----------
| 3  | name3|
 -----------
```

```
  requests
 ----------------
| Id | client_id |
 ----------------
| 1  | 1         |
 ----------------
| 2  | 1         |
 ----------------
| 3  | 2         |
 ----------------
| 4  | 3         |
 ----------------
| 5  | 3         |
 ----------------
```

I just want the result to show just clients that has only one request

```
result
 ----------------
| Id | name      |
 ----------------
| 2  | name2     |
 ----------------
```

How to make it in mysql or laravel elequent ????

Comment: Sorry, it is not so clear what your desired result?

Comment: I just want rows from clients that their `client_id` appears just one time only

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
DB::table('requests')->groupBy('client_id')->havingRaw('COUNT(*) = 1')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have working eloquent Models and relationships you could do:

```php
Client::has('requests', '=', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The next query should resolve your problem:

```
SELECT 
    clients.Id,
    clients.name
FROM requests
JOIN clients ON clients.Id = requests.client_id
GROUP BY clients.Id, clients.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
;
```